# ng-select with labelForId and id

Tags: angular-ngselect

It seems like if labelForId is used in a ng-Select (https://github.com/ng-select) which **also has an ID** it does not work, i.e. click on label does not jump into the element.

If I **do not put an ID in the definition of the ng-select** it works, but my IDE (intelliJ) throws an **"invalid id reference"**. Have a look on the attached image on https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/1993

```
div class="row margin-top-25">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label for="one">One (WORKS  but makes the IDE red)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
        <ng-select
                labelForId="one">
            <ng-option>Dog</ng-option>
            <ng-option>Cat</ng-option>
        </ng-select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row margin-top-25">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label for="two">Two (DOES NOT WORK ☹️)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
        <ng-select
                id="two"
                labelForId="two">
            <ng-option>Dog</ng-option>
            <ng-option>Cat</ng-option>
        </ng-select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

For everybody who has the same issue:
https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/1993#issuecomment-961218459